# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found in python

Tags: python, unicode

This is my code for boto3. I am getting a yaml output in AS. I am not able to figure out this error. What's wrong in my code. Thanks for help.

```
doc = '' 
AS = conn.describe_auto_scaling_instances(InstanceIds=[i.id])
with open(AS,'r') as file:
    doc = yaml.load(file)
    print doc
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:/Users/mvadaria/PycharmProjects/lambdaEC2/ec2autoshutAS.py", line 21,   in <module>  
    with open(AS,'r') as file:  
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found
```

Comment: Show the full traceback to the error.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mvadaria/PycharmProjects/lambdaEC2/ec2autoshutAS.py", line 21, in <module>
    with open(AS,'r') as file:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `AS` is a `dict`, not a file name. Perhaps one of the entries in the `dict` is the filename you need.

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html?highlight=describe_auto_scaling_instances#AutoScaling.Client.describe_auto_scaling_instances

Comment: Thanks for help. Got it